# Performing a Scheduled task from a Service and Keeping that service Alive

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

```
public class MyHibernatedService extends Service{ 
     public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //declaring the intents ..
        //some codes...

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, IntentServiceToBeRun, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 10000);  
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
}
```

I want my `Service` to launch an `IntentService` every single day at a certain time. However, I've read somewhere on the internet, StackOverflow, google,etc.. that a `Service` cannot stay alive forever, this is how Android works. It will have to kill that `Service` whenever Android needs memory or is using too much memory.
What guarantees for me that this code will run everyday and my `Service` will not be killed?

EDIT :

I noticed in the Android docs:

**The Android system will attempt to keep the process hosting a service around as long as the service has been started or has clients bound to it**

what do they actually mean by "clients bound to it"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your own service to periodically start another service, but use the `AlarmManager` service instead (like you are already doing). There is no need for this second service IMHO.

The `AlarmManager` is a system service and will never be killed by Android, and it already does exactly what your own service would do: start things periodically (or single-shot at a specified time).

On the "clients bound to it": off-topic, but it means other components (like other services, or activities) are connected to it using a call to `Context.bindService()`. For details, check the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to keep your service alive. 
Here you are setting the `AlarmManager`, that is able to wake your IntentService up when it is time, even if the phone is sleeping. This service does the job, not yours.

> What guarantees for me that this code will run everyday and my Service
>   will not be killed?

The code that you provided in `MyHibernatedService` has to be executed only once, to set the alarm, then you won't need it anymore. If it is the only thing that `MyHibernatedService` does, then you don't need it at all.

You could for instance create a static method in your intent service that would set the alarm, and call it from anywhere according to what you want (probably the place where you used to start `MyHibernatedService`).

Also, if you don't really need an incredible accuracy on the time your intent service is started, prefer `setInexactRepeating()` instead of `setRepeating()`.